# Android server notification implementation in app purchase

Tags: android, server, notifications, publish-subscribe, in-app-billing

Couldn't find any article or guid to implement in app pub/sub on android and docs are not very clear.

Tried reading docs but docs are cumbersome. Any guide or steps on how to implement this would be of great help for us developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pub/Sub is a bit complicated to work with in comparison with Apple's Server Notifications setup. I have an composed an article containing step-by-step instruction on how to setup server notifications for both iOS and Android.

[Configuring Server Notifications for In App Purchases](https://medium.com/@faiq.019/in-app-purchases-server-notification-19e4cb341977)

Comment: Thanks Faiq your article helped a lot.  I am accepting your answer.